# Adding array two other array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two `array()` My first array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ID] => 14212
            [TransactionNo] => 20160712-K-DTS2-14273
            [TransactionDate] => 2016-07-12T10:55:09.023+07:00
            [TotalTransaction] => 14000
            [LocationID] => 1
            [UserID] => 1224
            [CustomerCode] => K-DTS2
            [SendStatus] => true
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ID] => 14213
            [TransactionNo] => 20160712-K-DTS2-14274
            [TransactionDate] => 2016-07-12T11:24:31.84+07:00
            [TotalTransaction] => 12900
            [LocationID] => 1
            [UserID] => 1224
            [CustomerCode] => K-DTS2
            [SendStatus] => true
        )
)
```

and this

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 16:09:15:59
)
```

So my question is how to insert my second array to my first array. So the result become like this :

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [ID] => 14212
                [TransactionNo] => 20160712-K-DTS2-14273
                [TransactionDate] => 2016-07-12T10:55:09.023+07:00
                [TotalTransaction] => 14000
                [LocationID] => 1
                [UserID] => 1224
                [CustomerCode] => K-DTS2
                [SendStatus] => true
                [session_id] => 16:09:15:59
            )
```

I have try `array_merge` but the result doesn't like what i desire. When i use `array_merge` i get this result

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ID] => 2144
            [TransactionNo] => 20160713-K-LFJBLP-02158
            [TransactionDate] => 2016-07-13T11:32:33.6+07:00
            [TotalTransaction] => 74900
            [LocationID] => 1
            [UserID] => 11418
            [CustomerCode] => K-LFJBLP
            [SendStatus] => true
        )
      [session_id] => 16:09:19:52
)
```

here is my PHP

```
foreach ($xml->HeaderTemp as $HeaderTempnya)
        {   
            $HeaderTemp[] = $HeaderTempnya;
        }
```

Comment: add to both objects?

Comment: `foreach($array2 as $key=>$value) 
   $array1[0]->addChild($key, $value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bfahmi it almost working

Try to change it like this

```
foreach($first_array as $key => $value){
  $first_array[$key]->session_id  = $second_array['session_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($first_array as $key => $value){
  $first_array[$key]['session_id']  = $second_array['session_id'];
}
```

Comment: it become like this  [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [session_id] => 16:09:27:15
                )

            [ID] => 2161
            [TransactionNo] => 20160714-K-LFJBLP-02175
            [TransactionDate] => 2016-07-14T12:46:18.81+07:00
            [TotalTransaction] => 104500
            [LocationID] => 1
            [UserID] => 339
            [CustomerCode] => K-LFJBLP
            [SendStatus] => true
        )

Comment: @YVS1102; i correct the answer $key => $value not ($key as $value)